# two xp windows on same machine

Tags: windows-xp, mbr

When the computer start, it displays me two XP versions to choose from. One XP windows is the new installed windows OS on drive C and the other was on drive F , but it's content was formatted.

How can I get ride of that menu(removing the old windows item)

ty

Answer (score 2):

Using the Recovery Console, do `bootcfg /rebuild` and the computer will scan for Windows installations across partitions. That should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

1. From the desktop, hit your windows key and pause/break at the same time, or right click "My Computer" and choose properties.
2. From there, there will be an "Advanced" tab.
3. Hit the "Settings..." button under "Startup and Recovery"
4. Uncheck "Time to display list of operating systems"

I don't have XP installed anymore, but i believe there is also an option to edit your boot.cfg from this screen.  You can remove the erroneous entry there, however this is riskier than just not showing the menu.

Comment: You can specify the default OS on this screen. You can't edit the "boot.cfg" file from here. You are right though, you don't want to be messing with "boot.cfg" unless you can fix it if mess up. This is a good workaround until your next windows re-install.

Answer (score -1):

Start -> Run: `msconfig`

Select Boot tab. There you go.

(If you just want to hide the entry or want a different config utility, go to Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> `Startup and Recovery`.)

Comment: no boot tab on msconfig

Comment: Then the same Control panel, system, advanced, startup-recovery.. you dont have that also? Others same? Nice.

Comment: By the way, click BOOT.INI .. oh wait you have that. Seriously. I understand if someone can't read, can't understand whats written there. But giving out -1 ? Well...